# Why OpenGL does not overload its functions?

Tags: c++, opengl, overloading

*Recently*, I've started working with **OpenGL** using **C++**.

I'm annoyed by the way of declaring **Vertex** or changing current **Color**

the `glColor3f()` and `glVertex{2,3,4}{sdif}()` methods.

now then, why **OpenGL** don't overload those functions.

*for instance*, it will be better to type `glColor()` and `glVertex()` and they will be recognized by the number of parameters and their type.

*eventually*, the code will look much better and easier to read, with the same results.

I hope there's a good reason to **not** overload similar functions.

Comment: Many of the language-specific bindings do overload the OpenGL functions. But when you write in C/C++ you usually use the function names almost verbatim as they are defined in the specification. The one thing that differs is the prefixing of `gl` to the function names, this does not occur in the specification and to support the most languages possible instead of using namespaces, it was simpler to add `gl`.

Comment: It completely avoids the question (which has been answered already), but function overloading is considered harmful by quite a number of people. It can lead to a number of very weird effects and ambiguities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because OpenGL was originally designed with C as the primary language for its API, and C doesn't support function overloading.

---

However, quoting from Wikipedia:

> Although the function definitions are superficially similar to those
>   of the C programming language, they are language-independent.

It is always possible for OpenGL to have a C++ interface that supports function overloading and all the good stuff, though AFAIK there aren't any specification on that, and are mostly supported only with C++ wrappers.